# How to execute rules action programatically

Tags: 7, rules

Is it possible to execute a rule action upon form submission? I've created a rule and disabled it, so it'll be only called if it meets the condition I've set. Below is a sample code I've been using:-

```
function hook_form_FORM_ID_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  if ($form_state['values']['field_name'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] == 1)
    rules_invoke_component('rules_uncheck_update_checkbox', $form_state['commerce_order']);
  }
}
```

Not sure what are the other options as I've been stuck to make it work. Please help. Thank you.

EDIT:

Rules export

```
{ "rules_uncheck_update_checkbox" : {
"LABEL" : "Uncheck checkbox",
"PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
"ACTIVE" : false,
"OWNER" : "rules",
"REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "entity" ],
"ON" : { "commerce_order_update" : [] },
"IF" : [
  { "entity_has_field" : { "entity" : [ "commerce-order" ], "field" : "field_update_checkbox" } }
],
"DO" : [
  { "data_set" : { "data" : [ "commerce-order:field-update-checkbox" ], "value" : "0" } }
]
}
}
```

Comment: Hi Pierre, I've edited my post added the exported rules. I've also edited the rules_invoke_component() at the form alter code above. I would like to uncheck the field-update-checkbox upon saving the commerce order on commerce order edit page.

Comment: Make it active.  It won't fire, unless it's active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[rules_invoke_component](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!rules!rules.module/function/rules_invoke_component/7) is used to invoke a Rules Component.

In your case, it seems like you should invoke a Rules Event, using [rules_invoke_event](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!rules!rules.module/function/rules_invoke_event/7).

Comment: Hi Pierre, Thank you for responding. I haven't done this before, but is this correct rules_invoke_event('rules_uncheck_update_checkbox', $form_state['commerce_order'])? It's not being called. I have no idea why.